# PyAlgoTrade custom CSV date error Invalid datetime. It must be bigger than that last one

Tags: python, tensorflow, datetime, zipline, pyalgotrade

I am trying to add custom csv data into PyAlgoTrade using the `addValuesFromCSV` method, and I am getting this error:

```
2021-10-14 17:50:00 {'Open': 4886.0, 'High': 4888.0, 'Low': 4879.0, 'Close': 4883.0}
2021-10-14 17:55:00 {'Open': 4883.0, 'High': 4887.0, 'Low': 4874.0, 'Close': 4877.0}
2021-10-15 10:30:00 {'Open': 4910.0, 'High': 4922.0, 'Low': 4901.0, 'Close': 4907.0}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/60/1yz0pnwd2jv15p28bffgz8p40000gn/T/ipykernel_9157/639233146.py in <module>
      5 feed = csvfeed.Feed("Date", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      6 feed.addValuesFromCSV("data/5min/fcpo_dec_jan_contract.csv")
----> 7 for dateTime, value in feed:
      8     print(dateTime, value)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyalgotrade/feed/__init__.py in feed_iterator(feed)
     29     try:
     30         while not feed.eof():
---> 31             yield feed.getNextValuesAndUpdateDS()
     32     finally:
     33         feed.stop()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyalgotrade/feed/__init__.py in getNextValuesAndUpdateDS(self)
     88                     ds = self.createDataSeries(key, self.__maxLen)
     89                     self.__ds[key] = ds
---> 90                 ds.appendWithDateTime(dateTime, value)
     91         return (dateTime, values)
     92 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyalgotrade/dataseries/__init__.py in appendWithDateTime(self, dateTime, value)
    136 
    137         if dateTime is not None and len(self.__dateTimes) != 0 and self.__dateTimes[-1] >= dateTime:
--> 138             raise Exception("Invalid datetime. It must be bigger than that last one")
    139 
    140         assert(len(self.__values) == len(self.__dateTimes))

Exception: Invalid datetime. It must be bigger than that last one
```

Here is my data after 2021-10-15 10:30:00

| Date | Open | High | Low | Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-15 10:30:00 | 4910 | 4922 | 4901 | 4907 |
| 2021-10-15 10:35:00 | 4907 | 4907 | 4891 | 4896 |
| 2021-10-15 10:40:00 | 4896 | 4902 | 4886 | 4893 |
| 2021-10-15 10:45:00 | 4893 | 4901 | 4887 | 4897 |
| 2021-10-15 10:50:00 | 4897 | 4897 | 4879 | 4882 |
| ................... | .... | .... | .... | .... |
| 2021-11-15 17:35:00 | 4987 | 4989 | 4984 | 4985 |
| 2021-11-15 17:40:00 | 4985 | 4987 | 4975 | 4978 |
| 2021-11-15 17:45:00 | 4978 | 4990 | 4978 | 4987 |
| 2021-11-15 17:50:00 | 4986 | 4988 | 4970 | 4972 |
| 2021-11-15 17:55:00 | 4973 | 4975 | 4963 | 4965 |

Below is my code for the ingestion:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from pyalgotrade.feed import csvfeed

feed = csvfeed.Feed("Date", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
feed.addValuesFromCSV("data/5min/fcpo_dec_jan_contract.csv")
for dateTime, value in feed:
    print(dateTime, value)
```

I don't understand why is it saying that the last date is smaller then previous one.
Help would be much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Does it work when you remove the problematic rows from your CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the bars in the wrong order of timestamps

Have you tried checking if the data is sorted? maybe some issue with the datasource, maybe you can verify that once?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32670593)